# how to create article with multiple (unicode) languages

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode, linux

I want to create a book that will help Asian people learn English. The requirements are -
the book should contain text from 2 different languages, say, Hindi and English.

I tried [this multi-lingual example from here](http://tecfromelder.blogspot.in/2011/10/my-first-multilanguage-document.html)

```
\documentclass{article}
%Always start xelatex files with these in preamble. This helps in defining the script and fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
%Set the main languge next as main font.
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}

%Set rest of the languages l;ike this. Experiment a bit. script=punjabi did not work. Replaced with gurmukhi and it works.


%English does not need any script specifiction! Just define the font.
\newfontfamily{\eng}{Arial}
\begin{document}
%No need to define script as this is the manin font set. Like defalut.
नमो नारायणाय! \\

{\eng namo bhagavate naraayanaaya}\\
%the next line does not begin liekt he ones above. so it defaults to mainfont which is devanagari.
शुभम।
\end{document}
```

I used the following command
`$ xelatex multilang.tex`

but I got the error -

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, et
hiopic, farsi, arabic, pinyin, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, slovak,
 czech, danish, dutch, usenglishmax, ukenglish, finnish, french, basque, ngerma
n, german, swissgerman, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, german-x-2012-05-30, monogreek, g
reek, ibycus, ancientgreek, hungarian, bengali, tamil, hindi, telugu, gujarati,
 sanskrit, malayalam, kannada, assamese, marathi, oriya, panjabi, italian, lati
n, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, nynorsk, bokmal, indonesian, e
speranto, coptic, welsh, irish, interlingua, serbian, serbianc, slovenian, friu
lan, romansh, estonian, romanian, armenian, uppersorbian, turkish, afrikaans, i
celandic, kurmanji, polish, portuguese, galician, catalan, spanish, swedish, th
ai, loaded.
```

some more output and then this error -

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Lohit Hindi/ICU', contains ' '
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Lohit Hindi" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.5 \setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}
```

The questions are -

1. what is the exact problem here? It looks like the font "Lohit Hindi" is missing, but I am confused
2. how to install fonts in LaTex (or XeTex) or how to make the fonts installed on Linux available to XeTex?

Comment: XeLaTeX uses system fonts, so you have to install this font in the normal way for your operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you expect to see in your LaTeX / XeTeX output …

[image]

then you may just have to change the name of the font, which may be outdated in the example you got.

I modified your example like this (with comments removed):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit-Devanagari} % Hindi -> Devanagari

\newfontfamily{\eng}{Arial}
\begin{document}
नमो नारायणाय! \\

{\eng namo bhagavate naraayanaaya}\\
शुभम।
\end{document}
```

And if the Lohit fonts are missing on your system, you may find your luck [here](https://fedorahosted.org/lohit/) for Fedora and Debian, but also more crudely from git, svn and the like for any other system (see instructions there).

Worked for me on a RHEL6 derived system (Scientific Linux). Good luck!

Comment: Please note the difference in LaTeX betwenn a linebreak, a proper paragraph break and empty lines in the output. Right now, this is not the same as above.

Comment: @Johannes_B, you are right, although I believe that the empty line was not deliberately positioned like that in the original question. (There might be the same empty line missing after the part in latin characters.)
However I corrected it in my answer. Thank you!